# webpage data extraction automation

Tags: c#, python, ruby, web

Could you please suggest a platform that could extract webpage data (supporting elements like fields,buttons,links,label,grid data etc.) for webpage data extraction automating like Ruby,Python,C#,etc?

Comment: JavaScript/JQuery is always the tool for these purposes, but you can try using the BeautifulSoup in Python or XML DOM Library to extract the data. Similar Library might exist in Ruby and or C#

Comment: This has been truly discussed a trillion times...what have you researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) platform. It is a very high quality web automation and supports `C#,python,ruby,javascript,java,perl,and php`. One of the most important features are that it handles javascript really well.

Selenium Documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/).

## Edit

Ruby tutorial
http://anahorny.blogspot.com/2011/08/selenium-webdriver-ruby-tutorial.html

All documentation or other tutorials that you will need located here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Simple example:

Ruby:

```
@driver.get("https://demo.aravo.com/")
@driver.find_element(:id, "j_username").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "j_username").send_keys "sample"
@driver.find_element(:name, "j_password").clear
@driver.find_element(:name, "j_password").send_keys "sample"
@driver.find_element(:name, "login").click
@driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").send_keys "ruby fiel format"
```

Python:

```
driver = self.driver
driver.get("https://demo.aravo.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("j_username").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("j_username").send_keys("sample")
driver.find_element_by_name("j_password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("j_password").send_keys("sample")
driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
```

C#:

```
public void TheDriverTest()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://demo.aravo.com/");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("j_username")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("j_username")).SendKeys("sample");
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("j_password")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("j_password")).SendKeys("sample");
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("login")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Selenium is any Freeware/Open-source Software or what?

Comment: @user1897085 Yes, its all open-source. Here is their page on google-code, http://code.google.com/p/selenium/.

Comment: May i have any good tutorial from where i can learn about Ruby and Web automation? means all syntax and elements that Ruby has to work with webpage.

Comment: Can I use ruby any kind of data extraction from webpage- here the webpage i am talking about is the third party application,where i can view the source code,that's it!

Comment: @user1897085 what is the website?

Comment: Its an application into which we worked. but we sometimes need data to be collected,which are manually combersome to collect,So i am thinking about automation. https://demo.aravo.com

Comment: Could you give me a sample username and password?

Comment: I can give you the snapshot,but for that i need 10 reputation,userid and password can't be provided,it is company policy violation!

Comment: Okay,so which platform you would suggest me for such webpage automation is best and easy to install in my desktop? i will start then webpage data extraction/read on the basis of your feedback.

Comment: @user1897085 I think the easiest method is using python, well at least it is what I use. For speed better off using `c#` or `java`.

Comment: Does python will support me to get the all kind of webautomation? means table extraction data too? or clicking on anchor element n all?

Comment: @user1897085 it worked for me. Yes, you can do almost everything with python and selenium in web-automation.

Comment: Can you help me in my below post? --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886205/webpage-data-extraction-automation-using-python-and-selenium-webdriver