# Webpage data extraction automation using python and selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

May I know to have it work properly what are the software i need to install in my PC?

***UPDATE***

Error i was getting is this:

Getting this error when running `pip install -U selenium`. Mid way through the script, it gets the following SyntaxError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "C:\Python32\Scripts\build\rdflib\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from rdflib import __version__
      File "rdflib\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
        from rdflib.term import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Variable
      File "rdflib\term.py", line 367
        except TypeError, te:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\build\rdflib\setup.py", line 6, in <module>

    from rdflib import __version__

  File "rdflib\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>

    from rdflib.term import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Variable

  File "rdflib\term.py", line 367

    except TypeError, te:

                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Google will give you installation and usage instructions.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I am totally new this automation,so any reference from your side would better for me..

Comment: What os are you running?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question for SO.  Please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Your comment "For windows can you give me a screenshot like description,so that i can install it easily and get started all work" is the exact opposite of what we expect here, e.g. "Do your homework

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself . . . "

Comment: I agree, but to do research i also need the things to be installed in my PC all.Overall i would like to write down script for automation. but which one would be better to choose,is always good to ask to a senior who worked on such platform is no way a bad idea- I think @ernie. I did the same. If you don't want to give your time for that please ignore my post.

Comment: People those who are eager to help,let them do that! sharing knowledge is always a best practice!

Comment: Asking and learning, along with sharing and teaching, are all valuable.  On the other hand, asking w/o making any effort on your end shows laziness and no desire to learn, which is why the SO community tends to flag/downvote such questions.  If what you want is a complete solution, you should be using a freelance website.

Comment: I faced issue that's why i am here,otherwise Google is enough I know,If really google is enough such community hope nevers came to reality...

Comment: @ernie see my UPDATE in the description I was getting. Now it has been fixed up with the below help. So I told you that i did Google and then came here.But you didn't agree and rated my Post down vote. which seriously bad for me.. so now please rate it up.

Comment: @sr2222 please vote my post up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is python [here](http://www.python.org/download/) and selenium [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Windows 7 or another system:

To install `selenium`, extract `tr.gz` file, `cd` into the directory and then `python setup.py install`.

Or you could use `pip` like this:

`pip install -U selenium`

---

Specifically for linux, use

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

Installing on windows:

Download selenium from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and setuptools from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).
Extract them anywhere you chose, in this case I extracted them in`c:\Users\User\Desktop\..`.

Cd into the directory and then do `python setup.py install` if it says it cannot find python try `c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install` to first install setup tools:
[image]

Next cd into the seleneium directory and do `python setup.py install`:
[image]

If everything goes well there should not be any errors and you are ready to use selenium.
[image]

Comment: It's on PyPI too, so you could just pip or easy_install it...

Comment: In which directory i need to put the file? by the way i am using windows 7 PC.

Comment: @user1897085 If you mean the output of the extraction, you can extract it anywhere, but make sure to `cd` into wherever you put the directory.

Comment: I am not using Linux and Unix,but windows 7 i am using.

Comment: For windows can you give me a screenshot like description,so that i can install it easily and get started all work.

Comment: @user1897085 sure give me a second.

Comment: Yes,I am waiting fr your one... and thanks in advance you too!

Comment: @user1897085 yes i have virtual machine issues.

Comment: okay @eng,,till then i would wait.

Comment: once i would get,your one,I  will start my RND... :-)

Comment: @user1897085 okay it is updated.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and sugesstions too....Hope it will work for me,If any issues i will post back to you.meanwhile if any study guide you want me to refer please do... :-)

Comment: if possible please vote me up... any editor if you want can suggest me,so that i can code and debug there too... :-)

Comment: @user1897085 I already have, but for an editor I suggest using spyderlib or aptana studio.

Comment: People rate my post vote down,so i am not able to post any questions,so what should I do now? please advice me

Comment: Any idea what should i do?

Comment: please help me there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887819/webpage-filed-level-details-data-extraction-and-saving-it-to-excel-using-seleniu

Comment: @user1897085 Well for one you should improve your questions. Show some effort,show what you have tried what worked and what didnt. Show us trial and error.

Comment: I have given above what i tried,still i was banned to post Question. So can you advice how can or by whome i unbanned that?

Comment: From the setup tools i got .exe file "setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe".. the way you told is not happened with me. only the selenium .zip file i got and put it to the "D:\Python and Selenium" folder and the .exe file is also downloaded there. Now what should I do?

Comment: Please help me here for the same! as I am not able to do what you said in the screen shots.

Comment: @user1897085 lets take this discusstion to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21184/discussion-between-user1897085-and-enginefree)

Comment: Hi,It is resolved... can you look at my other post? :-)

Comment: @user1897085 what other post?